# Language and Platform

Tags: window, frame, video-capture, video-processing, frame-rate

I am really new to Windows platform.

I was wondering if you guys can give me a tip on which language to start on and which platform is the best  and easy to learn and use for the following

- I will be working on Video dissecting, frame rate measurement. Everything to do with video frames and image processing measurement.
- Performance is a very big concern. So I will not be able to work on Java or any other language. I would performance like C/C++.
- Please give me reference as to where I can start off on it too.

Is OpenCV a good choice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV is definitely a good place to start. The library is written in C++, have good API, and is highly optimized. OpenCV's cv::Mat data structure is fast and easy to work with and allows you to do linear algebra on matrices. The library has a large user community, so you should be able to find help on-line easily. You may use other libraries in conjunction with OpenCV or implement your own custom functions.

I would also suggest to use the power of GPU for image processing (when it is appropriate). OpenCV has a few functions that are implemented on GPU. This number will probably increase, because the library is being continuously updated (an updated version is released approximately every 3 to 4 months).

Answer (score 0):

Yes OpenCV is very good choice to start. Its very easy to learn since it is widely used and lot of help is available online. You can get things done with minimum code.